# How do I use the `every character` key in tikz decorations?

Tags: tikz-pgf, text-decorations, decorations, pgf-decorations

Assuming I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5cm]
      \node[draw, rectangle] (a) {A};
      \node[draw, rectangle,right of=a] (b) {B};

      \draw[postaction=decorate,decoration={raise=5pt, text along path,
      text={Foooooooo},text align=center}] (a) to[bend left] (b);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and I'd like to use the `every character` option which the Manual (p.605 in my version) documents as

> Set the effects that will be applied to every character in the
>   decoration text. The effects will typically be TikZ node options.

This sounds like it would do what I want, which is applying a background colour to every character, but I have been unsuccessful in trying to correctly use this key and have found no example anywhere. How do I use this option?

*EDIT:* Ok, `text effects/every character/.style={fill=red}` does not what I had in mind. It changes the fill colour, but also changes the position and direction of characters which now really look like individual nodes. They don't follow the path anymore but are all upright. Any way around that? I want them to follow the path, but simply have a background.

Comment: firstly you need to use `text effects along path` decoration (not the `text along path` decoration). Secondly try putting `text effects/every character/.style={fill=red}` in the decoration options (or whatever color you want).

Comment: That works indeed. Care to make an answer of your comment?

Comment: You can 'ping' somebody to ensure they see your message if you use, for example, @MarkWibrow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `every character` key only works with the `text effects along path` decoration:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.5cm]
\node[fill=red!50!orange] (a) {A};
\node[right of=a, fill=green!50!orange] (b) {B};

\draw [postaction=decorate, decoration={raise=5pt, text effects along path,
   text=FooBar!,text align=center,
   text effects/.cd,
     text along path,
     every character/.style={
       fill=blue!50!orange,
       text=white,     
     }}] 
  (a) to [bend left] (b);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suppose it's not possible to have the characters still be places such that they look to form a cohesive word, is it? I mean arranging them like they are without the text effects and only e.g. apply a background colour to all of them. As I understand, the characters are typeset individually anyway, event without the node style properties, so it should be possible.

Comment: @oarfish I think the `text effects/text along path` key is what you want as it automatically sets the `inner xsep` and `anchor` keys appropriately to give the illusion that that the text is written along the curve. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, what did you change in your code? I now manually set `inner sep` and `outer sep` and now it does what I want.